# How to write a continuously listening server as a service

Tags: c#, .net, windows, windows-services, client-server

I am writing one server which will listen for the client connections continuously. It doesn't need any user interactions. So, I am trying to make it as a service. I installed it successfully, but it didn't run successfully except for showing error 1053. I found that the start/stop method should return within 30 seconds. As far as I am concerned that means my server should halt its action and return within 30 seconds. I cant imply this constraint on the server because the client may connect at any time. Can anybody show me a way to install this server as a service?

Note 1: I am using windows platform, c# language and VS 2010.

Note 2: Other ideas are also welcomed.

Comment: You need to either start the server listening synchronously in a separate thread, or make your server work using the asynchronous versions of the socket functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing your code, and going on just what you are saying here I would say you should implement threading.

Right now your application starts running and just blocks until a client connects. That isn't best practice, or for a Windows Service it's even impossible because of the 30 sec. limit.

What you should do is start the service and initialize everything (so it will return within 30 sec.) and then start a different listening thread. What also might be a good idea is to start another thread when a client connects. In that case you can handle multiple clients instead of just one.

Of course I have no idea of what transport layer or such you are using, but check out this example based on TCP: http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/csharp-tutorial-simple-threaded-tcp-server